# what is the meaning of,Are you done?

Tags: american-english, colloquialisms

If someone is about to finish his or her lunch, and we want to know, can we ask him or her:

> Are you done?

Comment: It means that *are you finished having lunch* in this sentence, otherwise, it will refer to *have you completed your task*?

Answer (score 0):

it's somewhat rude to ask someone that WHILE they're still eating. "Are you almost/nearly done?" Would be better.

Also depends on the context. Are you waiting for them to finish so they can get back to work or are you waiting for them to vacate the table for you to use?

Comment: I am takling about the context that-when i went to the cafe,friends were having meal and suppose they were about to finish it.At that time,shall i say"Hey friends,are you almost done? or hey all of you done or what?Thanks a lot.